# need access to a search engine's database

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler

obviously, i think its overkill for me to run a spider that will crawl the internet autonomously like google or yahoos.

so i am wondering, if there is some way i can access a major search engine's database, instead of scraping them ?

Comment: are you trying to make a vertical / META search engine? if so, try Yahoo BOSS or google search APIs like Annie said

Answer (score 2):

Google and Yahoo both have APIs:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/
http://developer.yahoo.com/search/

But like everybody else said, we need more info about what you're trying to do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Other than doing regular searches, no.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You're already violating terms of use policy by scraping them. That kind of information is carefully guarded for obvious reasons.